# Core data objects actions from buttons

Tags: ios, core-data, uitableview, uibutton

In my app I am showing core data objects, in this case it is a Tasks Manager.
I have included a swip gesture to the rows, when the user swipes from left to right, an UIView is shown at the right side of the screen, like in the following picture:

[image]

This is the code for the handleGestureLeftRight method:

```
-(void)handleGestureLeftRight:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gec
{
    {
        
        CGPoint p = [gec locationInView:self.tableView];
        
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];
        
        
        if (gec.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
            
            
            NSLog(@"GESTURE LEFT-->RIGHT DONE");
            
            
          //BUTTONS AND LABELS DEFINITIONS ARE NOT SHOWN TO AVOID LONG CODE HERE

           
            
        }
        
       
        
    }
}
```

I would need your help on how to implement core data actions when the user taps on the buttons on the right side. As example, if the user taps on the Done button, the selected row object, should change the value of an attribute called isDone. The same should happen tapping to the other buttons, but a different attribute value should be changed.
Thank you.

Comment: You set attribute values on managed objects just like you do with any other object. They're Objective-C objects, they obey Objective-C rules.

Comment: Thank you @TomHarrington, but I guess that in this case each button will have an action:@selector(buttonaction) method, and how do I pass to it the core data object to be updated?

Comment: You don't pass selectors to objects to change their attribute values-- not for any Objective-C object. Change the attribute value in your button action method.

Comment: Would you mind giving me an example how to do this inside a button action method for the selected row(object)?

Comment: @mvasco: If you have the index path then `[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]` should be the corresponding Core Data object.

Comment: Thank you @MartinR, inside the handleGestureLeftRight method, I have NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p]; is this the indexPath you mean? But there are buttons on the UIView which call corresponding button actions, e.g. to update an attribute value from the selected Core Data object, my doubt now is: inside a button action method, how to use: [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath], that means how will the button action method know which object has to be updated? I kindly request you to put your comments into an answer...thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add the buttons to your table view in `handleGestureLeftRight:`, save
the selected index path in a property:

```
CGPoint p = [gec locationInView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];
self.currentIndexPath = indexPath;
```

Then, in the button action methods, you can access the corresponding Core Data object
with

```
YourEntity *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:self.currentIndexPath];
```

and update its properties. When removing the the buttons, set

```
self.currentIndexPath = nil;
```